# Why a single line is slower in Matlab profiler than when timing with tic command?

Tags: matlab, profiling

I am trying to measure the time of a piece of code, using both profiler and `tic` `toc` command. Like:

```
 tfconv_start=tic;
 for j=1:ordernum
      W_fft(:,:,j) = kernel_conv2fft_ver2(Mf,Hf(:,:,j),Hf_fft(:,:,j)./u,'same');
      Rffft=Rffft+mju(j)*(abs(W_fft(:,:,j).^2));
 end
 tfconv_elapsed=toc(tfconv_start);
```

`tic` `toc` tells me: 6.56s, while in profile it shows:

```
18.16      10   W_fft(:,:,j)=kernel_conv2fft_ver2(Mf,Hf(:,:,j),Hf_fft(:,:,j)./u,'same');
```

which means this line with 10 iterations costs 18.16s. I can not understand why it takes longer using profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem I found in the past is that the profiler somehow interferes with the JIT compiler. I was studying someone else's code with a lot of 'fortran-style' for-loops, which anyhow seemed to run pretty fast on the command line, probably due to the JIT doing its work. When running it via the profiler, it got more than a factor 10 slower!

if you are doing a lot of profiling, you might want to have a look at the excellent [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function) function on the file-exchange.

Comment: Note that in the latest version (R2013b), an updated version of `timeit` is supplied with MATLAB.